# Vue - i18n custom translations

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-i18n

I have VUE app with vue-i18n plugin.
I would like to load 'custom path' for translations when app is loaded.

The app is not loading the translations? What am I doing wrong?

`File: i18n/index.js`

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import Message from "@/localization/MyCity/en.json"

const i18n = createI18n({
  // default locale
  locale: "en",
  // translations
  messages: Message
});

export default i18n;
```

`File: main.ts`

```
import i18n from "./i18n";

const app = createApp(App).use(i18n)
app.mount("#app");
```

I tried the code above and the translations are not loading. Do you have any suggestions? This even might be the wrong approach to this problem. Do you have any other suggestion.

***Topic 2:***
Later on I will try and make dynamic translations based on deployment. I would like to make it fast and simple so I was thinking creating .env file with variable `MY_CITY_NAME` and do it like this  `import Message from "@/localization/${MY_CITY_NAME}/en.json"`.

Comment: While writing this question I found this [link](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/optimization.html#how-to-configure). Is this the way?

Comment: I read about it and found out a few things. You need to read about how Webpack is loading modules/packages. When app is started there cant be any variable.
Except if you set in your .env file as VUE_APP_your_variable. Than variable is going to be available.
You can get other translation files with modules.require() function. You can read more about this in Webpack documentation. And last but not least there is function in i18n that merges your files from different locales. `$i18n.mergeLocaleMessage`.
Sumup: read webpack, vue-i18n and env documentation for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem might be that you are not specifying language of your `Messages` object.

Try this:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
  ...
  messages: {
    en: Message
  }
});
```